# Display all resoult if text not cointaint strings from the list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Look ath this example

```
if ('.NET' or 'JS' or 'python' or 'Java') not in title:
    print(title)
```

It's a part of my code. Title is a string. I want to display title only if not contain any one element of the list. In this example it only exculdes .NET. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: What is the value of  `('.NET' or 'JS' or 'python' or 'Java')`?

Comment: If you try to run `'.NET' or 'JS' or 'python' or 'Java'` you will get `'.NET'`

Comment: I want that if only one element with this list will contain in title, it shouldn;t be print.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco So how can I solve my problem?

Comment: See  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-test-if-string-contains-element-from-list/

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your statement in this way:

```
if ('.NET' not in title and
    'JS' not in title and
    'python' not in title and
    'Java' not in title):
```

Or:

```
if all(x not in title for x in ('.NET', 'JS', 'python', 'Java')):
```

Comment: `('.NET' or 'JS' or 'python' or 'Java')` still resolves to just `'.NET'`.  Use `for x in ['.NET', 'JS', 'python', 'Java']` instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, sorry, I just copied and pasted the code from the question haha